# How to read CSV in pyspark with "," delimiter but not ", "

Tags: python, pyspark, delimiter

I am using the following code to read the CSV file in PySpark

```
cb_sdf = sqlContext.read.format("csv") \
                        .options(header='true', 
                                 multiLine = 'True', 
                                 inferschema='true', 
                                 treatEmptyValuesAsNulls='true') \
                        .load(cb_file)
```

The number of rows is correct. But for some rows, the columns are separated incorrectly. I think it is because the current delimiter is ",", but some cells contain ", " in the text as well.

For example, the following row in the pandas dataframe(I used pd.read_csv to debug)

| Unnamed: 0 | name | domain | industry | locality | country | size_range |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | cjsc "transport, customs, tourism" | ttt-w.ru | package/freight delivery | vyborg, leningrad, russia | russia | 1 - 10 |

becomes

| _c0 | name | domain | industry | locality | country | size_range |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | "cjsc ""transport | customs | tourism""" | ttt-w.ru | package/freight delivery | vyborg, leningrad, russia |

when I implemented pyspark.

It seems the cell "cjsc "transport, customs, tourism"" is separated into 3 cells: |"cjsc ""transport| customs|  tourism"""|.

How can I set the delimiter to be exactly "," without any whitespace followed?

**UPDATE:**

I checked the CSV file, the original line is:

`111,"cjsc ""transport, customs, tourism""",ttt-w.ru,package/freight delivery,"vyborg, leningrad, russia",russia,1 - 10`

So is it still the problem of delimiter, or is it the problem of quotes?

Comment: Please post sample data a text, not as images; see [ask]. If the field in csv contains a comma, the field needs to be in quotes. If your csv fields are not quoted, check with the producer of the broken output.

Comment: how about [trimming](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.trim) those columns after reading?

Answer (score 0):

I think that separating we'll have:

col1: 111
col2: "cjsc ""transport, customs, tourism"""
col3: ttt-w.ru,package/freight delivery
col4: "vyborg, leningrad, russia"
col5: russia
col6: 1 - 10

Comment: use cb_sdf = sqlContext.read.format("csv") \
                        .options(header='true', sep=',',
                                 multiLine = 'True', 
                                 inferschema='true', 
                                 treatEmptyValuesAsNulls='true') \
                        .load(cb_file)